# Trigger to count insert and updates from users

Tags: sql, oracle, count, triggers

I'm new with oracle sql. I am trying to make a trigger that counts when X user performs an update or an insert, but the TRANSACTIONCONTROL table shows it like this:

```
DATE--------- USER-----------INSERT----UPDATE
10/03/2022  UserParcial       1          0
10/03/2022  UserParcial       0          1
10/03/2022  UserParcial       1          0
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
DATE--------- USER-----------INSERT----UPDATE
10/03/2022  UserParcial       2          1
```

This is my trigger:

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER TRANSACTIONCONTROL_Trig
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE on products
for each row
DECLARE
dataTran date;
userTran varchar(30); 
InsertTran number:=0;
UpdateTran number:=0;

BEGIN
SELECT SYSDATE INTO dateTran FROM DUAL;
SELECT USER INTO userTran FROM DUAL;

    IF INSERTING THEN
    InsertTran := InsertTran  +1;   
    INSERT INTO TransactionControl(date, user, insert, updates) 
    VALUES(dateTran, userTran, insertTran, updateTran);
    END IF;
    
    IF UPDATING THEN
    updateTran:= updateTran+1;
    INSERT INTO TransactionControl(date, user, insert, updates) 
    VALUES(dateTran, userTran, insertTran, updateTran);
    END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get number of rows affected by a statement when inside that statement's trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770386/how-to-get-number-of-rows-affected-by-a-statement-when-inside-that-statements-t)

Comment: It Does'nt, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need *exact* numbers, than mining ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS periodically could probably suffice.  (I'm curious as to what business function having the count provides)

But if you really must use a trigger, then a compound trigger lets you keep counts at row level, but then summarise at statement level.

Some *pseudo* code below

```
create or replace trigger mytrig
  for insert or update on mytable
    compound trigger

  ins_cnt int;
  upd_cnt int;

  before statement is
  begin
    ins_cnt := 0;
    upd_cnt := 0;
  end before statement;

  after each row is
  begin
    if inserting then ins_cnt := ins_cnt + 1; end if;
    if updating then upd_cnt := upd_cnt + 1; end if;
  end after each row;

  after statement is
  begin
    insert into txn_control ( ... ) values (ins_cnt, upd_cnt);
  end after statement;

end;
/
```